# Angular 5 - Array of objects length = 0

Tags: angular

In app.component.ts file, I have an initialized array that will load objects, in the onInit event:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.pages = [];
}
```

Also in the OnInit event I have a setInterval method to evaluate an expression in milliseconds:

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (!this.isUser && !window.location.href.toString().toLowerCase().includes('localhost')) this.setUser();
}, 1000);
```

In the "setUser" method I load the "pages" array  by calling an api inside a loop.

```
private setUser() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.components.length; i++) {
      const component = this.components[i];
      this.http.get(urlApi + component).subscribe((data: any) => {
         let url = this.getURLComponent(component);
         if (url) {
           if (data) {
             this.pages.push({
               url: url,
               allowed: true
             });
           } else {
             this.pages.push({
               url: url,
               allowed: false
             });
           }
        }
      });
    }
    this.testAllowedComponents(pages);
}
```

In the same method (setUser), when I exit the loop I call another method passing it the array of objects as parameter:

```
testAllowedComponents(pages: any[]) {
    console.log('pages: ', pages);
    console.log('pages length', pages.length);
}
```

Now comes the problem when I access the method "testAllowedComponents" in first console I see it correctly (content pages):

```
[
   {
      "url":"/menu",
      "allowed":true
   },
   {
      "url":"/contact",
      "allowed":false
   }
]
```

But the second console pages.length is worth 0.

What could be the problem? Synchrony? when executing the loop to inside the setInterval?, thanks

Comment: I think it's because your console.log statement is not part of the subscribe method. I guess if you implement the observer interface (next, error and complete) it should work, check it out [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables#defining-observers).

Answer (score 0):

the most crucial issue here is synchronizing, whenever you send an AJAX request it will call callback asynchronously, so all the methods after this callback will call immediately (will not wait for callback to execute), so this will be order of execution

```
console.log("Order 1"); // First call
this.http.get("/api").subscribe(()=>{
   // it will execute last time
})
console.log("Order 2"); //It will call immediately after first call
```

now in your case, whenever you iterate through for-cycle, `testAllowedComponents` method will call immediately after each iterate, but AJAX request is unpredictable, maybe it will call on some iterations maybe not (whenever it will return from server), so you need to synchronize somehow, you could achieve this with RXJS and array operators.
you need to do the following things:

- you need to convert components array into the stream
- you need to convert these streams into the AJAX request streams
- you need to put all the    logic inside subscribe method

Solution:

```
private setUser() {
    //Now we have streams instead of comps array
    const streams$ =from(this.components)
         .pipe(swictchMap((comp)=>this.http.get(urlApi + comp)
         .pipe(map((response)=>({ data:response,comp:comp }))));

    from(streams$).subscribe(({comp,data})=>{
      let url = this.getURLComponent(component);
     if (url) {
       if (data) {
         this.pages.push({
           url: url,
           allowed: true
         });
       } else {
         this.pages.push({
           url: url,
           allowed: false
         });
       }

       this.testAllowedComponents(pages);

    })
```

the hardest part here I think is the first one, so I'll explain it a bit. we are taking all the components turn them into the observable, and after each fire we transform it into the AJAX request stream and return as ajax response as comp object (because you used it inside getUrlComponent method). lastly we call subscribe method, and it will be called after each iteration, and call testAllowedComponents after each iteration

Comment: Thank you, very interesting what you tell me, I have implemented it, but at the moment it has not worked for me, maybe I did it wrong, I will continue testing

Comment: yeah if you have some issues or questions, don't hesitate and ask me here :) I'll help you as much as i can